# how to use html5 verification before ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

My goal is: 
- use HTML5 verification form submit
- use ajax checks

if these 2 tests are ok, then submit the form.

I have written:

```
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
email = $("#email").val();
password = $("#password").val();    
$.post("ajax.php",{action:"checkLogin",email:email, password:password},function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data=="ok") {
        $("#formLogin").submit();
    } else {
        bootbox.alert("Bad email or password");
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

When data=="ok", it has passed the HTML5 checking and the ajax checking: how do I submit the form from that point ?